# How to add space before and after edited text in contenteditable area

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I want to add space before and after edited text in contenteditable area like one space before and after so how can i do that using CSS. this is my script : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talabe/6bxvhc1f/)

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    
}

[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
    background-color: white; 
 color : black; 
}
span.a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  
}
span.a:empty {
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
   <span  class="a" contenteditable="true">
    when an unknown printer
    </span> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
   It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
   and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Comment: on double click, selecting a word add a space behind it, is that not enough ?

Comment: @G-Cyr I want the whole proccess to be automatic so users when the edit text ; there will be one space before and after the edited text

Comment: does `[contenteditable="true"]::before,[contenteditable="true"]::after {content:' ';}` enough then ? https://jsfiddle.net/mfkh39yt/

Comment: @G-Cyr I am really grateful your solution is really working .

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```
[contenteditable="true"] {
  margin: 0 5px 0;
}
```

This will add spacing on either side of the contenteditable area.

```css
[contenteditable="true"] {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
    
}

[contenteditable="true"]:focus {
    background-color: white; 
 color : black; 
}

[contenteditable="true"] {
  margin: 0 5px 0;
}

span.a {
  border: 1px solid white;
  
}
span.a:empty {
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, <span  class="a" contenteditable="true">when an unknown printer</span> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```